# How to use Dynamics OData to query for either account or contact

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, odata

We are using Dynamics 365 cloud CE and for integration we use the Odata webapi.

We have accounts for companies and contacts for individuals, together either can be a customer. We are creating incidents and in Dynamics it is possible to do a lookup for a customer either in account or contact.

Now I wish to do the same but through the webapi. Is that possible? In that case how?

Of course, one possibility is to make a call for contact and if it doesn't exist call for an account. But is it possible to do it in one call?

...dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts/?$select=contactid&$filter=ssn eq 'SE190001010101'
...dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts/?$select=accountid&$filter=ssn eq 'SE190001010101'

If not in contact it should be found in account.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you will have to perform individual update (contact or account) per API call.

Customer field is polymorphic lookup i.e it can point to contact/account.

But at the end account and contact are individual entites.

Comment: But only for read? Is it possible to to a query for ssn on either of them in one query?

Comment: nope you cannot raead as well, There is another way for your req,, there is something called [Relevance search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/relevance-search) in dataverse. Take a look at this might be helpful